# Custom taxonomies, with custom rewrites/slug, AND loading a taxonomy archive template from a plugin

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, register-taxonomy

I think maybe my understanding about rewrites and templates for custom taxonomies and CPTs is wrong and maybe someone here could help me solve my problem and educate me.

So I have a post type, "wiki-doc" and a post type "wiki-news".  Each has been set up with custom slugs:

wiki-doc has its rewrite set to:

```
'rewrite' => [
    'slug' => 'wiki/documentation',
],
```

wiki-news has its rewrite set to:

```
'rewrite' => [
    'slug' => 'wiki/news',
],
```

And that works how I expect it too.  `mysite.com/wiki/documentation` loads an archive template and template conditional of `is_archive()` with the the wiki-doc post type.

BUT, I also have a custom taxonomy called `wiki-help-topic` which has the rewrite of:

```
'rewrite' => [
    'slug' => 'wiki/help-topics',
],
```

However this slug doesnt work.  `mysite.com/wiki/help-topics` throws a 404. `mysite.com/wiki/help-topics/term-whatever` does work however, AND the template conditional is `is_tax()` which is what I want.

I tried adding this rewrite rule:

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^wiki/help-topics?$',
        'index.php?taxonomy=wiki-help-topic',
        'top',
    );
```

But now the page loads `is_home()` which is weird.

So thats the first issue.

The second related issue is that I would also like some custom rewrites to show a list of all `wiki-doc` posts tagged with a `wiki-help-topic` term, BUT I would like it to use a taxonomy archive (conditional `is_tax()`)

My rules keep using the `is_archive()` conditional and thus the archive template, for example:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
  '^wiki/documentation/help-topic/([^/]+)?$',
  'index.php?post_type=wiki-doc&wiki-help-topic=$matches[1]',
  'top',
);
```

This loads all `wiki-doc` posts tagged with `wiki-help-topic` but it uses an archive template and not a taxonomy template.

Is it possible to have this URL use `is_tax()` instead so that I can use a specific template file for that taxonomy or taxonomy term?

Comment: I've left a start on a response breaking down the behaviors you've described. I will double back and edit in a solution for the former issue when you elaborate on your desired outcome - what do you wish to be displayed at `mysite.com/wiki/help-topics`? A list of wiki-help-topic terms? An archive of all posts with any term from that taxonomy?

Comment: @bosco I was thinking I would show an archive of all posts with any term from that taxonomy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Background & Core Functionality

### Why a Taxonomy Path Slug Alone Produces a 404

> However this slug doesnt work. mysite.com/wiki/help-topics throws a 404.

WordPress does not provide a mechanism for "an archive of taxonomy terms" out of the box - that is, neither the template hierarchy nor the `WP_Query`/`WP_Tax_Query` logic support a direct display of terms within a taxonomy - rather both are designed to route requests to queries for `post` content. I think the decision to omit this behavior is reasonable, as the content that one might wish to display when a request is made for a type of taxonomy varies a lot between use-cases.

This is apparent in a vanilla installation by attempting to visit the address `/index.php?taxonomy=category` or `/category` assuming a pretty permalink structure (I will assume the popular `/%category%/%postname%/` configuration for the rest of this response).

Because that mechanism does not exist, WordPress does not generate rewrite rules for the base `/category` URL (visiting that path does not produce the query `index.php?taxonomy=category`) so the URL path processing falls back on more global rules, and `/category` is ultimately interpreted as though it were a page slug and - assuming you have not created a page with the slug `category` - WordPress produces a 404 response as no such page exists.

> `mysite.com/wiki/help-topics/term-whatever` does work however, AND the template conditional is is_tax() which is what I want.

By providing a term that URL path now maps properly into the rewrite rules generated for your taxonomy registration, and WordPress is able to use a complete `WP_Tax_Query` clause to retrieve `post`s.

### Why a Taxonomy Query Variable Alone Produces the Home/Front Page

> I tried adding this rewrite rule: [...] But now the page loads is_home() which is weird.

Just as WordPress does not build routes for isolated taxonomy slugs, when parsing query parameters into a query/query vars, `WP_Query` uses the following logic to build a `WP_Tax_Query`:

```php
if ( ! empty( $q['taxonomy'] ) && ! empty( $q['term'] ) ) {
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => $q['taxonomy'],
    'terms'    => array( $q['term'] ),
    'field'    => 'slug',
  );
}
```

Thus, since `/index.php?taxonomy=wiki-help-topic` does not include a taxonomy term, it is completely ignored in the composition of the main query, and an empty query produces the home page.

### Template Hierarchy Selection Precedence

> The second related issue is that I would also like some custom rewrites to show a list of all wiki-doc posts tagged with a wiki-help-topic term, BUT I would like it to use a taxonomy archive (conditional is_tax())

The query composed from the parameters `?wiki-help-topic=some-topic&post_type=wiki-doc` should produce a `$wp_query` reflecting both `is_tax()` as well as `is_post_type_archive()` and `is_archive()` - in fact, if a query `is_tax()` or `is_post_type_archive()` it is implicitly `is_archive()` as well.

You can see [the code in `WP_Query` which determines these properties](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d6cc4f1aecaafc21f5c40b707fdba240cc37564b/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L892) here.

Counter-intuitively, it looks like [the code determining which object is considered "the main queried object"](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d6cc4f1aecaafc21f5c40b707fdba240cc37564b/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3487) gives precedence to the taxonomy over a post type, but [the code which determines which template hierarchy entry point to load](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/270f2011f8ec7265c3f4ddce39c77ef5b496ed1c/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L57) gives precedence to a post type archive template over a taxonomy template...

I'm really not sure if that's a bug, or if the loaded template is often at odds with the queried object.

## Solutions

### Routing Taxonomy Root Requests to all Posts in Taxonomy

There are a few different ways to handle this, but I think the most useful is to transform requests targeting a taxonomy without terms into ones targeting every term within the taxonomy:

```php
/**
 * Transforms incoming queries specifying a taxonomy slug but no terms into a
 * query targeting all terms within that taxonomy. Note that this handles the
 * specific case of the "taxonomy" query variable being set and the "term"
 * query variable unset - it does not address the case of a taxonomy-specific
 * query variable being present but empty.
 * 
 * @param WP $wp The WP class instance representing the current request.
 **/
function wpse388742_parse_taxonomy_root_request( $wp ) {
  $tax_name      = $wp->query_vars['taxonomy'];

  // Bail out if no taxonomy QV was present, or if the term QV is.
  if( empty( $tax_name ) || isset( $wp->query_vars['term'] ) )
    return;
  
  $tax           = get_taxonomy( $tax_name );
  $tax_query_var = $tax->query_var;

  // Bail out if a tax-specific qv for the specific taxonomy is present.
  if( isset( $wp->query_vars[ $tax_query_var ] ) )
    return;
  
  $tax_term_slugs = get_terms(
    [
      'taxonomy' => $tax_name,
      'fields'   => 'slugs'
    ]
  );

  // Unlike "taxonomy"/"term" QVs, tax-specific QVs can specify an AND/OR list of terms.
  $wp->set_query_var( $tax_query_var, implode( ',', $tax_term_slugs ) );
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse388742_parse_taxonomy_root_request' );
```

Performing this transformation so early lets WordPress set up the rest of the request and query as it normally would, meaning the resulting `WP_Query` object will appropriately reflect `is_tax()`, `is_post_type_archive()`, and `is_archive()` without any further work.

You can then explicitly route requests to the taxonomy slug with a rewrite rule as you have done in your question, or you can use a `registered_taxonomy` action hook to expose the behavior for all publicly queryable taxonomies:

```php
/**
 * Rewrite requests for the isolated slug of publicly queryable taxonomies to
 * a request specifying the taxonomy without specifying any terms.
 *
 * @param string   $name The name of the registered taxonomy.
 * @param string[] $types An array of object type names which the taxonomy is associated with.
 * @param Array    $tax The WP_Taxonomy object, cast to an associative array.
 **/
function wpse388742_register_tax_root_rewrite( $name, $types, $tax ) {
  if( empty( $tax['publicly_queryable'] ) )
    return;

  $slug = empty( $tax['rewrite'] ) || empty( $tax['rewrite']['slug'] ) ? $name :  $tax['rewrite']['slug'];

  add_rewrite_rule( "^$slug/?$", "index.php?taxonomy=$name", 'top' );
}

add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'wpse388742_register_tax_root_rewrite', 10, 3 );
```

### Template Precedence

We can use a simple `template_include` filter hook to use your taxonomy archive template in those specific conditions - I believe this should work, assuming that the taxonomy term is indeed the queried object (`get_taxonomy_template()` depends on it being so in order to construct the correct contextual template file paths):

```php
function wpse388741_doc_help_topic_template( $template ) {
  if( is_tax( 'wiki-help-topic' ) && is_post_type_archive( 'wiki-doc' ) )
    return get_taxonomy_template();

  return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse388741_doc_help_topic_template' );
```

This in place, the query described by `?wiki-help-topic=some-topic&post_type=wiki-doc` should use the taxonomy archive template instead of the post type archive template.

The behavior could be genericized to apply to all taxonomy/post type pairs by removing the string arguments from the `is_` conditionals.

Comment: Thanks @bosco that explains a lot.  To answer your question in the comment above, I want ```mysite.com/wiki/help-topics``` to use either my taxonomy-help-topics.php template or even just all archive of all posts with any term from that taxonomy.  Not picky but I want to use a specified template file so I can create some sort of "term index" with a feed.

Comment: @rugbert pardon the delayed response! That's great - all of the posts using the taxonomy is much more direct than a list of terms in the taxonomy. I think mapping that request to a query asking for all posts which don't have a term in an empty term list should work - I'll test and post back here in a few hours

Comment: @rugbert added a solution. It was a little more convoluted than I was hoping, but I think it's pretty solid.

Comment: Take my bounty, brilliant @bosco!  This is all very informative and I have a much better understanding on the inner workings of WP routing so this little project I am working on is going to be much better thanks to you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This was a nice refresher for me as well :) . If you really want to dig into WordPress's request routing behaviors, take a look at some of the information collected in the `$wp_rewrite` global, like `$wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules()`, as well as a bunch of the information exposed on the `$wp` global - between the two of them you can see all the rules WordPress will apply against a request URI in order, as well as which one matched the current request and what querystring WordPress transformed the request into. Can be super useful in debugging rewrites!